# Deserialize a class to a dictionary in c# using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or JObject.Parse

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am making a small API project in Asp.Net Core 2.2 which fetches data like countries, currencies, languages etc(static data).

Assume I have a JSON format as below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "countries": [
      {
        "translatedName": "Ascension Island",
        "translations": [
          {
            "languageCode": "bg-BG",
            "translatedName": "Остров Възнесение"
          },
          {
            "languageCode": "cs-CZ",
            "translatedName": "Ascension"
          }
        ]
   }
}
```

I want only to get the JSON text within `data` tag object and deserialize it to this class:

```
class Country
{
      public string TranslatedName { get; set; }

      public Dictionary<string, string> Translations { get; set; 
}
```

So the idea is that the key of the dictionary would be languageCode and the value would be translatedName.

The `data` object will be present in any kind of response I get, while for the other part it might change. It might be `data -> countries`, or `data -> languages`, or `data -> currencies` etc.

so the method to parse would look like below;

```
public T Parse<T>(string fieldName, string json)
{

}
```

the fieldName will determine the second child name after `data` key, so the structure would always be `data -> fieldName`. I can replace the unused(*data key*) part from JSON just by saying `string.Replace(...)` but was thinking if there is a better way to do this!

Second issue is how I can I deserialize the translations to the dictionary ?

I tried doing something like this in the method:

```
public T Parse<T>(string fieldName, string json)
{
    return JObject.Parse(json)[fieldName].ToObject<T>();
}
```

So if I use this method like this:

```
var countries = Parse<List<Country>>("countries", ....); //it fails due to the fact it does not know how to convert translations to dictionary
```

I really appreciate any help for this:

Comment: For the first issue, I normally just use a wrapper: `public class Wrapper<T> { public T Data { get; set; } }` and use that for deserialization

Comment: "_key of the dictionary would be languageCode and the value would be translatedName._" Unfortunately, there is no direct mapping from the json to what you try to do. Json objects can be represented as dictionaries, however the keys of such a dictionary would be the json property names. Based on your json, such a dictionary would have for example the string `"languageCode"` as key, with a string value of `"bg-BG"`. You would need to process the json objects from the "translations" list and build your dictionary accordingly...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yeah I was thinking the same actually but then I got messed up with second part and somehow totally forgot for the wrapper (palmhand)

Comment: Would there be any issue to keep it all strongly-typed and create a Translation class so you would use `public List<Translation> Translations { get; set; }`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the problem is that in the second step I search on translations and if its a List then its not that performant compared to dictionary. So the only reason I want to have a dictionary is to improve the search performance. I can add one more property and create that dictionary based on the list but was thinking if there is a better way, and since this is a library the consumer would be confused which property to use because one of them should be nullified since it is cached later. So if the consumer tries to use Translations list then gets a null exception

Comment: Are there so many entries there that the performance would actually be hindered? Have you tested that? It would seem this is a non-issue

Comment: Your comment in your last code snippet "_//it fails due to the fact it does not know how to convert translations to dictionary_" seems to be in contradiction to the `Country` class you have shown, or is at least confusing/ambiguous. In `Country`, `Translations` is clearly a list, yet your comment talks about an error that seems to see Translations not as a list, but as a dictionary.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes they are, the endpoint might be hit 200 times per second and the complete json is 30000 lines of code, I dont think there is a need for performance test but if there is no solution I can make some

Comment: @elgonzo totally right, corrected that :(

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. It doesn't matter if there are 500000 countries if each country only has 2 translations, a Dictionary for those translations is not needed. You could need a Dictionary for the countries themselves, but that's another problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto every country is translated between 30 - 50 languages, but the search on the list would happen for each country which means you will end up searching the whole thing in linear way(maybe not the whole list but alot i would say)

Comment: The structure then seems completely wrong, you should have a dictionary of language codes and the translations that language has as array values of those codes

Comment: The structure is in the api and can not be changed unfortunately. Also there is a good reason why you dont want to change it since you might want to get only countries without translations. If you change the structure it would be harder to achieve this. Anyhow since its an existing api I can not change this, my only concern is if what i need is possible or not :)

Comment: Fixing two errors in the JSON, probably due to you not posting it completely, I had no issues deserializing this. I only added this class: `public class CountryTranslations { public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I could resolve the issue:

For the first problem as suggested by @Camilo I created a wrapper.
For the second I created a custom JsonConverter which made the job for me like below.

```
internal class TranslationsToDictionaryObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(List<CountryInfoModel>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) 
            || typeof(List<CurrencyInfoModel>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in token)
            {
                dict.Add(item["languageCode"].ToString(), item["translatedName"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }

        return dict;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

After that the model would look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class CountryInfoModel 
{
    public int BwinId { get; set; }

    public string TranslatedName { get; set; }

    public string TwoLetterCode { get; set; }

    public bool LoginAllowed { get; set; }

    public bool RegistrationAllowed { get; set; }


    [JsonConverter(typeof(TranslationsToDictionaryObjectConverter))]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly did you do that? I told you, it works with the default serializer. You are doing something wrong

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto here is a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQlfF7#, check the error

Comment: Because the structure is wrong, you have `Dictionary<string, string> Translations` when you should have `List<Dictionary<string, string>> Translations`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto to me does not make sens to create a dictionary for each translation, at the end a translation is a key-value pair (twoLetterCode - translatedName) not e dictionary, you can go that way as well but there is no benefit especially when it comes to searching because you still have to search on  the list and then get the data from the dictionary which only contains an entry

Answer (score 0):

Here i created this function for you, tested and it work with your json string.

```
var json = "{ data: { countries: [{ translatedName: 'Ascension Island', translations: [{ languageCode: 'bg-BG', translatedName: 'Остров Възнесение'}, { languageCode: 'cs-CZ',translatedName: 'Ascension' }]}]} }";
List<Country> countries = Parse<List<Country>>(json, "data.countries");
public static T Parse<T>(string json, string key)
{
    var rss = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken jtoken = null;
    foreach (var k in key.Split('.'))
    {
        if (jtoken != null)
            jtoken = jtoken[k];
        else jtoken = rss[k];

    }

    return jtoken.ToObject<T>();
}
```